# automatically add additional space for annotations while keeping layout the same

Tags: margins, geometry, todonotes, marginnote

Consider, I've got a document I am asked to review in a way, that I add todonotes/marginnotes with comments.

Therefore the usual document margin might be to small. Is there a way to just add additional space for todonotes while keeping the documents layout unchanged? I know that there are ways of changing margins, page geometry etc. but is there a neat way, where I just would need to add one line of code in the header, to have wider margins during the reviewing process? That is also important since I do not always overlook all the layout settings the author has made to his tex document, so I am likely to change something when setting the wider margins by hand. Furthermore ideally I would like to not mess up with marginnotes.

So basically consider a layouted letter page document. I just want to add additional space, so have additional space on the right of the letter document.

Is there a neat way?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
% loads of unknown author specific packages, settings, layouting
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
This is some text to review.
\todo{This would be my comment on some extra wide margin just for todonotes.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text/142258#142258, and if you need more than one type/recipient of note, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% loads of unknown author specific packages, settings, layouting
\usepackage[textwidth=\dimexpr\marginparsep+4cm\relax]{todonotes}


\begin{document}
This is some text to review.
\todo{This would be my comment on some extra wide margin just for todonotes.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this work with scrartcl as well? Tried in another document as well but I get "you can not use \dimexpr ...". I still try to boil down this document to see where the problem occurs..

Comment: @johanaLK `\dimexpr` is really just fluff here, you could use `textwidth=5cm` or any other fixed length.

Comment: @johanaLK should work with anything, it just directly sets the width of the `minipage` used internally for the note. If you make it wider than `\marginparwidth` (as here) you get an overfull box warning but it's only a warning and turning it off would mean patching todonotes internals.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to somehow work. Nevertheless it just uses up all the space that is available but does not extend the pagewidth if needed.. So what I actually want is kind of "gluing some more paper next to the original document and write my notes on that extra sheet"..

Comment: @johanaLK OH OK you are not going to _print_ this then (dynamically extending real paper is harder:-)  Just set `\pdfpagewidth` to some arbitrary large amount, it won't affect latex at all but will change the clip area in your viewer

Comment: Hm, pdfpagewidth does not do the job. I've got a solution using geometry, but it requires me to fiddle around myself for every new document I get..

Comment: @johanaLK should work as long as you set it after geometry  has