# Saving counters

Tags: macros, counters

Consider the situation:

1. Two authors A,B (in fact, it will be four) inserting comments on a `tex` file.
2. Each author has his own command `\alertA` and `\alertB` to insert comments.
3. Each author should has his own counter `\ctrA` and `\ctrB` which will be used during the comments.
4. The command `\alert<?>{foo}` should print the value of `\ctr<?>` at the position and insert at the margin again the value of the counter followed by `foo`.
5. Each author has his own colour `\clr<?>` to be used for the output of his comments.

**Partial code**

I tried to define a global command `\alert` with 3 arguments: `clr`, `ctr` and `text`.

The `clr` should be optional, with default value `black`. If no colour is passed, the comments should be black.

`\alert[red]{A}{foo}` should make use of the counter `\thectrA` to insert `foo` and of course, step the counter.

Further, I simply have to define the commands `\alert<?>` with one argument (the comment) to be passed to `\alert`.

```
\newcommand{\alertA}[1]{\alert[blue]{\thectrA}{#1}}
\newcommand{\alertB}[1]{\alert[red]{\thectrB}{#1}}
```

The use in the text should be simply

```
... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertB{more comments here} and so on...
```

At the end I'd like to have two independent sets of comments with two enumerations and two colours.

**M(non working)WE**

As you can see there is a problem with the counters. They are constant equal to 1.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{alert}
\newcounter{ctrA}
\newcounter{ctrD}
\newcounter{ctrM}
\newcounter{ctrT}
\setcounter{alert}{1}
\setcounter{ctrA}{1}
\setcounter{ctrD}{1}
\setcounter{ctrM}{1}
\setcounter{ctrT}{1}

\newcommand{\alert}[3][black]{% #3=texto, #2=ctr #1=color
\renewcommand{\thealert}{#2}
\rlap{\textsuperscript{\textsuperscript{\textcolor{#1}{\textbf{\thealert}}}}}%
\marginpar{\raggedright\footnotesize\textcolor{#1}{\llap{\textsuperscript{\textit{\thealert}}}#3}}%
\stepcounter{alert}%
}

\newcommand{\alertA}[1]{\alert[red]{\thectrA}{#1}}
\newcommand{\alertD}[1]{\alert[blue]{\thectrD}{#1}}

\begin{document}
... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You never step `ctrA`.

Comment: This answer might be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for an `alert` counter. Just use a counter-per-author. Here is what I would do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{ctrA}
\newcounter{ctrB}

\colorlet{clrA}{red}% Author A colour
\colorlet{clrB}{blue}% Author B colour

\newcommand{\alert}[3][black]{% #3=text, #2=ctr #1=colour
  \textcolor{#1}{\textsuperscript{#2}}%
  \marginpar{\raggedright\footnotesize\textcolor{#1}{\textsuperscript{#2}~#3}}%
}

\newcommand{\alertA}[2][clrA]{\refstepcounter{ctrA}\alert[#1]{\thectrA}{#2}}
\newcommand{\alertB}[2][clrB]{\refstepcounter{ctrB}\alert[#1]{\thectrB}{#2}}

\begin{document}
... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertB{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertB{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertB{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertB{more comments here} and so on...

\end{document}
```

Each author have an associated counter and colour (defined using `\colorlet`). Each author-counter is stepped with a call to the appropriate `\alert`: `\alertA` for author A and `\alertB` for author B.

Comment: I didn't know about the `\colorlet`. Thanks so much.

Comment: only `\textsuperscript` will affect the formatting of the text. So I decided to use `\rlap`. But a zero width box is more appropriate.

Comment: @Sigur: The formatting within the text and margin paragraphs were not really a concern in the question nor my answer. As such, I've removed all that. You can format them however you want them.

Answer (score 1):

You're never stepping the counters. The `alert` counter is not needed: just redefine `\thealert` to be `\the<counter>`. I also simplified the code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{ctrA}
\newcounter{ctrD}
\newcounter{ctrM}
\newcounter{ctrT}

\newcommand{\thealert}{} % initialize

\newcommand{\alert}[3][black]{% #3=texto, #2=ctr #1=color
  \stepcounter{#2}%
  \renewcommand{\thealert}{\csname the#2\endcsname}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{1.4ex}[0pt]{\tiny\bfseries\color{#1}\thealert}}%
  \marginpar{%
    \raggedright\footnotesize\color{#1}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\textsuperscript{\itshape\thealert}}#3%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\alertA}[1]{\alert[red]{ctrA}{#1}}
\newcommand{\alertD}[1]{\alert[blue]{ctrD}{#1}}

\begin{document}
... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

... as we have\alertA{comments here} and so on...

... after a lot of text\alertD{more comments here} and so on...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, I tried to use `\the#2` but I see that the trick is `\csname the#2\endcsname`. Nice!

Comment: @Sigur If you do `\renewcommand{\thealert}[1]{\the#1}`, then when `\thealert` is called you get `\the•c•t•r•A` (I use • for separating tokens): five tokens, not one. With `\csname the#1\endcsname` one token is formed, equivalent to `\thectrA`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your code after defining counters width:

```
\setcounter{alert}{0}
\setcounter{ctrA}{0}
\setcounter{ctrD}{0}
\setcounter{ctrM}{0}
\setcounter{ctrT}{0}

\newcommand{\alert}[3][black]{% #3=texto, #2=ctr #1=color
%    \renewcommand{\thealert}{#2}
\stepcounter{alert}%
\rlap{\textsuperscript{\textsuperscript{\textcolor{#1}{\textbf{\thealert}}}}}%
\marginpar{\raggedright\footnotesize\textcolor{#1}{\llap{\textsuperscript{\textit{\thealert}}}#3}}%
}
```

With it I got:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort but your code has a single enumeration. I wish two independent.

Comment: Hm, I miss this. I'm just curios, why you not use ``todo`` package for this?

Comment: as I wrote, I'd like to have a very different list of comments for each author. See the output. I can use different colours and numbers.