# Highlighting paragraph as own opinion

Tags: environments

Has anyone a suggestion what one could do to mark some parts of a text as "own opinion?".

I am writing a report on which basis the team will decide further steps. So I am reviewing several approaches and I would like to somehow include some "meta" thoughts/criticisms in the report as well. But they should be easily spotted by a reader as my own subjective opinions/ recommendations as distinct from the objective review of the methods.

I was thinking of maybe a vertical line in the margin, spanning one or multiple paragraphs, with some text say something like 'things to keep in mind'. But I am open to any suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps the package `todonotes` is useful. However, marginal comments are not great if you have lots to say.  If you are wordy, consider setting your comments between the normal paragraphs, and use a different (i.e., smaller) font size and switch from a serif to a sans serif font.  If you are inclined to shiny bells and whistles, then consider using `tcolorbox` to box the text or put a line on one (or more) sides, add shading, etc.  Easy to make the potential mistake of making your opinion stand out *more* than the report -- though maybe that's a good thing at the discussion stage....

Comment: Yes I am using todo for simple comments to myself and the reviewers. I decided against them for these 'my own opinion' parts, because they will include considerable amounts of text as well as math and stuff.

Comment: the shading option is not too bad, ideally I would like to have some text in the margins 'explaining' why these parts are shaded

Comment: @P.R. It they are comments in the middle of paragraph, may be `\newcommand*\personalopinion[1]{\textcolor{orange}{$\langle$\emph{#1}$\rangle$}}`. And if you need more than one paragraph, may be a `tcolorbox` that puts a vertical line on the lateral?

Comment: it wont be comments in the middle of a paragraph. From my current use, I think it will span at least on paragraph but stay within one (sub/subsub)section. I am looking in tcolorbox now

Comment: I do not want to have comments on comments, so nesting is not an issue. Using todo with `inline` would work as a work-around, but again it might not be immediately obvious to the reader what that colouring means.

Comment: Here's a method, if you wanted comments from different users (or on different topics, or of different importance) to be color coded, either intertext  or collected at the end: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160

Answer (score 1):

Often, less is more.  Compare a simple implementation and a fancier one.  Not much is, if anything, is gained beyond demonstrating a knowledge of specialized packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}
\tcbset{breakable, enhanced jigsaw}% + other stylings...
\usepackage{lipsum, kantlipsum}
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}#1\end{tcolorbox}}

\newcommand{\xcomm}[1]{%
  \begin{quote}
    \footnotesize\sffamily \textsc{\textbf{commentary}}.\quad #1
  \end{quote}}

\newcommand{\xproem}[1]{%
  \begin{quote}
    \footnotesize\sffamily \textsc{\textbf{note}}.\quad #1
  \end{quote}}

\begin{document}


\xproem{Text set in this style represents my reflections on this project}

\lipsum[1]

\xcomm{\kant[1]}

\lipsum[2]

\xcomm{\kant[2]}

\lipsum[3]

\xcomm{\kant[3]}

\lipsum[4]

\xcomm{\kant[4]}

\lipsum[5]

\xcomm{\kant[5]}


% Or this -- but what does the colours and boxing add?
\newpage
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{Note:} All text with this background represents a my own comments.
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]

\comm{\kant[1]}

\lipsum[2]

\comm{\kant[2]}

\lipsum[3]

\comm{\kant[3]}

\lipsum[4]

\comm{\kant[4]}

\lipsum[5]

\comm{\kant[5]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the first version. different than I envisioned it first, but I agree with you that less is more in this context

Comment: @P.R. -- Cheers.  I often struggle between balancing what is useful, simple, and elegant with my desire to do "cool" things in LaTeX just because I can. Aside from learning from others, this site is also a good outlet for relieving the pent-up desire to do or see the cool stuff.