# List of todos per chapter

Tags: todonotes

For a longer document I would like to add a list of the todos of each chapter at the end of that chapter.

I have searched for a while and read the documentations of todo, easy-todo and todonotes and it seems that all packages only support one list at the very end of this document.

For example with easy-todo, compiling this code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{easy-todo}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
Some text
\todo{do this}
\todo{do that}
\listoftodos

\chapter{Second chapter}
Some text
\todo{do something else}
\todo{do this too}
\listoftodos
```

gives me a list with all four todos in chapter  1, and an empty list in chapter 2.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: My answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160 could be adapted in that, instead of using different todo's for different people, it could be applied to different chapters.  Of course, it does not use the `todo` package and so the appearance is completely different.